# Dynamic Pivot SQL Server Not Showing Value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I have the following table:

```
oCode       oDateTime         oValue
---------------------------------------------
A           2017-01-01       10
B           2017-01-01       20
C           2017-01-01       5
```

I want to have the following result:

```
oDateTime        A         B        C
------------------------------------------------
2017-01-01       10         20       5
```

If Static Pivot, I would use the following code:

```
select 
   *
from 
   (
    select 
       sTag
       , sDateTime
       , sValue
    from #condesarsp
   ) src
   pivot
   (
      sum(sValue)
      for sTag in ([X1], [X2], [X3])
   ) piv
   order by sDateTime;
```

But unluckily, The `oValue` is not shown. Its just showing `null` value. Is there a typo on the code above?

After, I want to have dynamic pivot. So I don't need to define the column, It's just generate from `oCode` value.

Need help, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ya there is some mistakes in your query. You have to give the `oCode` like `A,B,C` instead of `[X1], [X2], [X3]`. Like this:

```
for sTag in (A, B, C)
```

So the corrected code is:

```
select 
   *
from 
   (
    select 
       oCode
       , oDateTime
       , oValue
    from condesarsp
   ) src
   pivot
   (
      sum(oValue)
      for oCode in (A, B, C)  -- This line is changed.
   ) piv
   order by oDateTime;
```

Follow the link for demo:

> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/06a9d/3

**Dynamic Query:**

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(c.oCode) 
            FROM condesarsp c
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT oDateTime, ' + @cols + ' from 
            (
                select oCode
                       ,oDateTime
                       ,oValue
                from condesarsp
           ) x
            pivot 
            (
                 sum(oValue)
                for oCode in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '


execute(@query);
```

Follow the link to the demo:

> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/06a9d/7

Comment: this is great! Cheers,

Answer (score 3):

First, you would required to specify `max()` function rather than `sum()` and other `sTag` has value should be [A], [B], [C] rather than [X1]..[X3]

```
select *
from 
(
    select 
           oCode, oDateTime, oValue
    from table
) src pivot(
      max(oValue)
      for ocode in ([A], [B], [C])
) piv
order by 1;
```